# Pi3 won't boot Assertion 'str' failed at ../src/basic/utf8.c:195

Tags: pi-3, boot, raspbian-stretch

I have an raspberry pI 3 that won't boot.  The problem is probably the sd card since it works when I switch to another sd.  During the boot screen the PI give me

> "Assertion 'str' failed at ../src/basic/utf8.c:195 ......"

There is a number of text when the Pi boots it hangs on that line. Is there any way to salvage the sd card or fix this issue?

I was working with a board and external power supply.

Comment: Where does the error message come from? Is it from the operating  system? Is it from a program starting at boot time? What operating system you are using? How do you "switch" to another SD Card? Do you clone the first one?

Comment: No, there is a number of text when the Pi boots it hangs on that line.  I am using latest PI OS stretch.

Comment: Have you tried to reflash the faulty SD Card with a default Raspbian Stretch image?